# How does one debug infinite recursion in Haskell?

Tags: debugging, haskell, profiling

How would one debug this (obviously) flawed program using GHC's profiling tools?  The program enters an infinite recursion within the second clause of `frobnicate`.

```hs
-- Foo.hs
frobnicate :: Show a => Maybe a -> String
frobnicate Nothing = ""
frobnicate x       = case frobnicate x of
  "" -> "X"
  _  -> show x

main :: IO ()
main = print (frobnicate (Just "" :: Maybe String))
```

The example might look contrived, but it's actually stripped down version of a real bug I encountered today.

In an imperative language one the mistake would be obvious as the stack trace would say something like `frobnicate -> frobnicate -> frobnicate -> ...`.  But how would one discover this in Haskell?  *How would one narrow down the blame to this one particular function?*

I tried something akin to the following:

```sh
ghc -fforce-recomp -rtsopts -prof -fprof-auto Foo.hs
./Foo +RTS -M250M -i0.001 -h
hp2ps -c Foo.hp
```

where the `-M250M` flag is added to ensure it doesn't kill the machine, `-i0.001` increases the profiling frequency in an attempt to catch the overflow in action (which happens very fast).

This produces this rather unhelpful plot:

[image]

There is no obvious overflow in this plot.  The y-axis doesn't go past even a single megabyte!  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you run your program with `+RTS -xc`, GHC will print a stack trace if your program encounters an error. You just have to wait for some memory error to occur, although I believe some versions of GHC will consume memory almost indefinitely.

Comment: `+RTS -h` gives you a heap profile.  Don't be surprised stack use doesn't show up on it...

Comment: @Carl: I realised that as I was writing the question earlier but I figured to ask anyway since I didn't know how to debug stack overflow.

Comment: @user2407038: that flag was very helpful, thanks!  However, I found that it needs to be combined with `-auto-all` to produce useful results.  Feel free to add that as an answer.

Comment: The way you find an infinite loop (interrupt it and examine the stack) is also useful for finding non-infinite loops (plain old slowness). Just interrupt it more times. If you see something you could remove on two or more interrupts, removing it will give you a healthy speedup.